# I am trying to create a minecraft server but every time I start it I get an error, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, minecraft

```
: [org.antlr.v4.runtime.ConsoleErrorListener:syntaxError:38]: line 1:0 token recognition error at: '~'
Exception in thread "main" [15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.<init>(Ljava/util/jar/Manifest;)V
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.createCodeSource(SecureJarHandler.java:66)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader$DelegatedClassLoader.findClass(TransformingClassLoader.java:275)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader.loadClass(TransformingClassLoader.java:136)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader.loadClass(TransformingClassLoader.java:98)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.service.modlauncher.ModLauncherClassProvider.findClass(ModLauncherClassProvider.java:67)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.launch.platform.MixinConnectorManager.loadConnectors(MixinConnectorManager.java:70)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.launch.platform.MixinConnectorManager.inject(MixinConnectorManager.java:59)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.launch.platform.MixinPlatformManager.inject(MixinPlatformManager.java:196)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinBootstrap.inject(MixinBootstrap.java:202)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinLaunchPluginLegacy.initializeLaunch(MixinLaunchPluginLegacy.java:201)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinLaunchPluginLegacy.initializeLaunch(MixinLaunchPluginLegacy.java:195)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchPluginHandler.lambda$announceLaunch$9(LaunchPluginHandler.java:97)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at java.util.HashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchPluginHandler.announceLaunch(LaunchPluginHandler.java:97)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:52)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:82)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.runLauncher(ServerMain.java:63)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.access$100(ServerMain.java:60)
[15:07:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:         at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:57)
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodException. Somewhere you are calling a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: ava version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)

I do not know how to check my modlauncher version, what does it mean? and how do I check it?

Comment: how can I not call the method that doesnt exist? what can I change?

Comment: so should I change my java version? and if yes, can you send a link, because I cant find any older version

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Joundill why not move it instead?

Answer (score 5):

This is [McModLauncher/modlauncher#91](https://github.com/McModLauncher/modlauncher/issues/91). Short explanation: In Java 8u321, Oracle changed `public ManifestEntryVerifier(Manifest man)` to `public ManifestEntryVerifier(Manifest man, String manifestFileName)`, which broke all existing code that called that constructor. You can either work around the problem by downgrading to a previous build of Java 8 (such as 8u311 or 8u312), or fix it by upgrading modlauncher <del>(though as of the time of this writing, no release contains the fix, so you'd have to build what's in Git yourself)</del> (which has been done as of Minecraft Forge 36.2.26).

Comment: The joy of using internal, undocumented APIs.

Comment: For people who are finding this now: this problem has been fixed in McModLauncher and incorporated in Forge, minimum Forge version for the fix is 36.2.26 per https://github.com/McModLauncher/modlauncher/issues/91#issuecomment-1058754244